# transition makes elements move on page load

Tags: html, css, transition

I just made a circle menu and it worked correctly.
but the problem is when i open it on browser and the elements just start to move because of the transition i gave to opener class.
idk what to do, i'd be thankful if you guys help me!

Well, this is my html codes :

```css
/*reset*/

*,
*::before,
*::after{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul,li{
    list-style: none;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

img{
    display: block;
}

/*default*/

body{
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
}

/*start*/

#btn{
    display: none;
}

.main{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #3f3faf;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
}

.opener {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #3f3faf;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0); 
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-size: 0;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all .4s;
    
}

.op-1{
    transition-delay: .1s;
}

.op-2{
    transition-delay: .2s;
}

.op-3{
    transition-delay: .3s;
}

.op-4{
    transition-delay: .6s;
}

.op-5{
    transition-delay: .7s;
}

.op-6{
    transition-delay: .8s;
}

#btn:checked~.opener {
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
    font-size: 30px;
}



#btn:checked~.op-1{
    left: 55%;
    top: 30%;
}
#btn:checked~.op-2{
    left: 60%;
}
#btn:checked~.op-3{
    left: 55%;
    top: 70%;
}
#btn:checked~.op-4{
    left: 45%;
    top: 30%
}
#btn:checked~.op-5{
    left: 40%;
}
#btn:checked~.op-6{
    top: 70%;
    left: 45%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Circle Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn">
    <label for="btn" class="main icon-menu"></label>
    
    <div class="opener op-1 icon-google2"></div>
    <div class="opener op-2 icon-facebook2"></div>
    <div class="opener op-3 icon-telegram"></div>
    <div class="opener op-4 icon-twitter"></div>
    <div class="opener op-5 icon-linkedin"></div>
    <div class="opener op-6 icon-pinterest"></div>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

whenever i open it on chrome, the elements start to go behind the btn i made becuase of the transition.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Echoing the previous comment, but a functioning example here would be very useful.  I took the time to copy-paste all of this to a Fiddle and honestly it looks fine to me, so I don't currently understand what the problem is.

Comment: oh ok thanks for your guide i'll do that. and for the issue, try to refresh the page and you'll see the elements are trying to go to the center at first seconds.